# GIT: Pushing to remote repository doesn't work (Code 128)

Tags: git

I use Magit in Emacs to control my source code.
A while ago I set up a remote repository in a Dropbox-Folder. It's just a Test so far, I didn't share it with anybody yet.

The Problem is, that I can't push to my repository anymore. I've commited a couple of changes and also started a new Branch, but I cant push to it anymore. This is the error-message

```
$ git --no-pager push -v origin new-proj-setup:refs/heads/new-proj-setup
Pushing to /Users/Henning/Dropbox/Consulting/Repo/consulting.git
fatal: '/Users/Henning/Dropbox/Consulting/Repo/consulting.git' does not appear to be a git     repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
git exited abnormally with code 128.
```

I am using two machines, and it's possible that I only pushed from the other machine so far. But my user.name and user.email should be the same.

Thank you for your help!

PS: The Repository isn't broken, I can still clone the Project.

Comment: You have write permissions and such to the folder?

Comment: I guess I should, it says:  drwxr-xr-x 340 Feb 20 16:42 consulting.git - Is that how I check?

Comment: You say cloning still works; do you use the exact same "URL" to clone the repo? And have you tried if you can push to it from a new clone?

Comment: well, this did it... It's stupid, but I forgot that my User-Directory is different for the two computers. I specified the right path and now it's working. =)

Comment: If you put your comment answer as a real answer, I'll up vote it.  Just had this issue and my path was incorrect too.